# No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I can't run test on my device and getting error `No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.` Here is my test class:

```
package com.pecode.itrustyou.ui.login;

import android.support.test.filters.MediumTest;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import com.pecode.itrustyou.R;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@MediumTest
public class LoginActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void enterInvalidPassword() {
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.etEmail)).perform(typeText("email@gmail.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.etPassword)).perform(typeText("asdgfhj"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withText("The username and password combination is invalid")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

Here is my build gradle. I've added all test dependencies but nothing working. And I've done everything that is described here: [Run espresso in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099011/run-espresso-in-activityinstrumentationtestcase2/36101556), added AndroidJUnitRunner in default configs.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pecode.itrustyou"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.1.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://test-itrustyouservices.azurewebsites.net"'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://api.itrustyou.io"'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def formattedDate = new Date().format('dd.MM.yyyy')
            outputFileName = "ITrustYou-${formattedDate}.apk"
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    ///viewModel
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
    //recyclerView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //constraint layout
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
    //circleImageView
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    ///barcode
    implementation(name: 'LibPdf417Mobi', ext: 'aar')
    //ui
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    //eventbus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    //support
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    //CrashLytics
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

    // Espresso dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use **ALL** AndroidX dependencies in your build.gradle (app)

```
// Core library
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
// AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
// Espresso dependencies
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.1'
```

So change this line

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

to this

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
```

and don't forget to use AndroidX testInstrumentationRunner in your defaultConfig

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: yes, that was an issue - mixing AndroidX dependencies with regular

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that service testing in Android should be done in its own scope. When you create an Android project, three packages are created in it:
One is the main project
The other is Android tests related to services and views written in front of it (androidTest).
And the last package of other tests written in front of it (test).

I had to move my test to the androidtest folder and add the relevant dependencies via androidTestImplementation
The related dependencies are as follows :

```
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:(last version)'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:(last version)'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:(last version)'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:(last version)'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:(last version)'
```